# msg not getting printed in struct msghdr in linux kernel

Tags: linux, sockets, kernel

I am using kernel `4.5.3` , and i am working on to implement new Layer 4 transport protocol (essentially a new socket). From user space app, when i send data through my new socket, i am receiving it in kernel. In kernel i am trying to unwrap the buffer and trying to verify if all is correct. The user data send from user space is wrapped into `struct msghdr` structure by socket layer of linux kernel (so i this portion has to be bug free). It is this structure i am trying to print in my kernel handler of the new socket specific sendmsg fn. Though i am able to print all the fields, except when i print the actual msg send (char *) , it is printing blank.

Below is the dump fn i have written:

```
static
void dump_msg_hdr(struct msghdr *msg){

    struct sockaddr_in *dest_addr = NULL;
    struct in_addr dest_ip;
    char ipv4[32], *usermsg = NULL;
    struct iovec *iov = NULL;

    memset(&dest_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    memset(&dest_ip, 0, sizeof(struct in_addr));
    dest_addr = (struct sockaddr_in *)msg->msg_name;
    dest_ip = dest_addr->sin_addr;
    getDotDecimalIpV4(htonl(dest_ip.s_addr), ipv4);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Dest ip address = %s", ipv4);
    iov = msg->msg_iter.iov;
    usermsg = (char *)kmalloc(iov->iov_len, GFP_USER);
    memcpy(usermsg, iov->iov_base, iov->iov_len);
    printk(KERN_INFO "user msg = %s\n", usermsg);
    printk(KERN_INFO "msg->msg_iter.count (no of data bytes) = %d", msg->msg_iter.count);
    printk(KERN_INFO "iov_base = 0x%x, iov_len = %d\n", iov->iov_base, iov->iov_len);
    printk(KERN_INFO "msg->msg_iter.nr_segs (no of iovec segments) = %d", msg->msg_iter.nr_segs);
    kfree(usermsg);
}
```

**output**

```
Dest ip address = 192.168.6.6
user msg = <blank>
sg->msg_iter.count (no of data bytes) = 27
iov_base = 0xbf95c153, iov_len = 27
msg->msg_iter.nr_segs (no of iovec segments) = 1
```

**structures**

```
struct iov_iter {
int type;
size_t iov_offset;
size_t count;
const struct iovec *iov; /* SIMPLIFIED - see below */
unsigned long nr_segs;
};

 47 struct msghdr {
 48         void            *msg_name;      /* ptr to socket address structure */
 49         int             msg_namelen;    /* size of socket address structure */
 50         struct iov_iter msg_iter;       /* data */
 51         void            *msg_control;   /* ancillary data */
 52         __kernel_size_t msg_controllen; /* ancillary data buffer length */
 53         unsigned int    msg_flags;      /* flags on received message */
 54         struct kiocb    *msg_iocb;      /* ptr to iocb for async requests */
 55 };
```

Comment: What **exact** message you send from the user-space application?